# Dojo 1.4 how to bind an object

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is my code:

```
dojo.provide("test.validation");

dojo.declare("test.validation", null, {
    addValidate : function(a) {
        this.a = dijit.byId(a);
        var link = dojo.connect(dijit.byId("form"), "onclick", this.validate);
    },

    validate : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this);
        if (!this.a.isValid()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I would like call this: `this.a.isValid()` function, but I'm out of my object scope.

How can I bind it to that onclick event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried reading about [dojo.hitch()](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/hitch?highlight=%28dojo%5C.hitch%29)?
It deals exactly with those kind of problems.